# Want to view EMACS Messages buffer while EMACS loads

Tags: emacs

I use

```
(message "..some text...")
```

in my init file to send messages to the Message buffer while EMACS loads. This is a quick way for me to see where a change I have just made crashes the startup.

However, I have not been able to find a way view that buffer during the load and watch the messages scroll. I always have to switch to it after a loading failure to see where it occcured.

Is there anyway to view the messages being sent to the Messages buffer (not the echo line) while Emacs is processing the init file?

Comment: See this related thread -- **"What causes emacs to not display the mini-buffer or window while starting up?"**:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16674/what-causes-emacs-to-not-display-the-mini-buffer-or-window-while-starting-up

Answer (score 2):

How about putting

```
(view-echo-area-messages)
```

at the beginning of your `init.el`?

Or if you instead want the messages buffer to take up the whole screen,

```
(with-current-buffer (messages-buffer)
  (goto-char (point-max))
  (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer)))
```

However, putting messages in your init-file is a crude workaround. You probably actually want to launch Emacs with the `--debug-init` option:

```
$ emacs --debug-init
```

This will halt on the error and present you with a backtrace.

Or alternatively, you could just `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and reload your init-file (`M-x load-file RET ~/.emacs.d/init.el RET`).